# Increase 3D Graph thickness for 3D printing in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, 3d-printing

My code:

```
Plot3D[{(2*x*y)/(x^2 + y^2)}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

Output:

[image]

And now I can export this to STL by using the export STL command, however, when I try to print this on the MakerBot 3D printer there is a problem because the width of the graph is too thin. I need to increase the thickness of the width of the graph, can I do this in Mathematica?

Comment: Try with `RegionPlot3D[]`

Comment: I'm confused by your terminology. What do mean by "width" and "thickness"? I have no idea what dimension "width" refers to, and as for "thickness", a surface it infinitesimally thin by definition.

Comment: Here's an article about 3D printing from Mathematica... there are some tricks to take note of. http://www.segerman.org/3d_printing_notes.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
Plot3D[{(2*x*y)/(x^2 + y^2)}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 PlotStyle -> Thickness[1]]
```

[image: thick]

And remember to watch your units - if you print in millimetres, 1 is a bit small...

## For Version 10

The above no longer works in *Mathematica* version 10. Instead of `Plot3D`, use `ParametricPlot3D`:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, (2 x y)/(x^2 + y^2)}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
 PlotStyle -> Thickness[1]]
```

[image: still thick]

Comment: This may be version 9 and later, not sure...

Comment: What about [`AbsoluteThickness`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AbsoluteThickness.html)? edit: it seems it's not supported.

Comment: @shrx `AbsoluteThickness` doesn't appear to work for this application...

Comment: @MichaelE2 :) our answers reflect our contrasting math skills...

Comment: This seems to be a special-case plot style for `Plot3D`, `ParametricPlot3D` and perhaps others, which does just what I tried to do in my answer (expand along the normals), but with proper `VertexNormals` along the edges.  Undocumented (as far as I can see).

Answer (score 22):

In version 10.0.0 the `PlotStyle -> Thickness` method shown by cormullion does not appear to work. Instead we can use the undocumented `Extrusion` option:

```
ContourPlot3D[x y z == 0.05, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, Extrusion -> 0.1]
```

[image]

Comment: Aaaaaaagh. They're supposed to add new features for new releases, not remove ones..

Comment: Which works in ContourPlot3D even though it's Red so unrecognized as an option but doesn't work and is rejected by ListContourPlot3D!!! Echoing Aaaaaaaagh.  V. 10.1.

Comment: @Ymareth Seems `Extrusion` (still undocumented) works now also in `ListContourPlot3D` since v10.2. See [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/98142/19960)

Comment: @Ymareth  To avoid Red , `Method -> {"Extrusion" -> .1}`

Answer (score 19):

You can take advantage of the `VertexNormals` that `Plot` computes to translate the surface a little to each side.  I'm not sure just what is required for good STL output.  I put a polygonal side all around the two surfaces.  The `VertexNormals` are wrong for the sides, so I commented them out for the image presented.

The thickness is controlled by the parameter `thickness`.

```
With[{plot = Plot3D[{(2*x*y)/(x^2 + y^2)}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Mesh -> None]}, 
 With[{n0 = VertexNormals /. Cases[plot, HoldPattern[VertexNormals -> _], Infinity],
       thickness = 0.1}, 
  With[{pts = First @
         Cases[plot, 
               GraphicsComplex[p_, e__] :> Flatten[{p - thickness n0, p + thickness n0}, 1],
               Infinity],
        vn = First @ Cases[plot, HoldPattern[VertexNormals -> v_] :> Join[v, v], Infinity]},
   Graphics3D[
    GraphicsComplex[
     pts,
     {EdgeForm[],
      Cases[plot, Polygon[p_] :> Polygon@Join[p, p + Length[pts]/2], Infinity],
      Cases[plot, 
       Line[p_] :> Polygon[Join[#, Reverse@# + Length[pts]/2] & /@ Partition[p, 2, 1]],
       Infinity]}
     (*, VertexNormals -> vn *)
     ],
    PlotRange -> All,
    Options[plot]
    ]
   ]]]
```

[image: Graphics]

Comment: This was a very detailed answer, and I appreciate you taking the time to write it. I chose the other only out of simplicity but I am sure your answer may have future benefits, thanks.

Comment: Hey, no problem.  The other way is definitely superior based on simplicity.  Also, the other answer does what this one does and more.

Answer (score 7):

As of Version 11 there are the `PlotThemes` `"ThickSurface"` and `"FilledSurface"`.

```
Plot3D[{(2*x*y)/(x^2 + y^2)}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotTheme -> "ThickSurface"]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[{(2*x*y)/(x^2 + y^2)}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotTheme -> "FilledSurface"]
```

[image]

Comment: Can Mathematica 11 vary the value of "ThickSurface"? If yes how? Could you share a line of code? I have this: PlotTheme -> "ThickSurface" but the thickness is to big. thank you

Comment: @M.Joe I think you'll adapt Simon Wood's answer by using the undocumented option `Extrusion`.