# Apply an image as a texture to text

Tags: image, text, textures

I have the following equation

```
eq = Sum[x^2, {x, 0, 10}]
```

and an image `image = Import["http://creativity103.com/collections/Graphic/rainbowbars.jpg"]`.

How might I output a transparent version of the equation above with the image used as a **tile** for the text.

For example I'm looking for something similar to this gradient image expect for the text above.

**Edit: it wasn't very clear in the question, but I am looking to tile the background image if possible.**

[image]

Comment: I'd like a new formulation for the question. If you put a transparent text on top of an image, well, then you get the same image. There are several different way to use an image as a tiling, so be more precise.

Comment: @Pickett Included an image.  Basically I'm looking to do something similar to a gradient but with an actual image.

Comment: Your added screen shot doesn't show any kind of a background behind the text, so I still don't get what you are looking for.

Comment: @m_goldberg I believe it is fixed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`ImageAdd`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageAdd.html) is your friend:

```
image = Import["http://creativity103.com/collections/Graphic/rainbowbars.jpg"];

text = HoldForm @ Sum[x^2, {x, 0, 10}];
img2 = Image @ Rasterize @ Style[text, 100, Bold];

rainbow = image ~ImageResize~ ImageDimensions[img2] ~ImageAdd~ img2
```

[image]

---

With [Pickett](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/731/pickett)'s extension for outlining:

```
img3 = ColorNegate[img2] ~Dilation~ 2 // ColorNegate;

rainbow ~ImageSubtract~ img2 ~ImageAdd~ img3
```

[image]

Comment: I've already up-voted this, but it would be even better if the text were outlined as shown in the question. Without a black outline the text is difficult to read for those, like me, who have poor vision,

Comment: @m_goldberg Tomorrow

Comment: [Here](http://pastebin.com/ekL4T39R)'s one way ([image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1ryq5.png)).

Comment: @Pickett Thanks!  I'll include it in my answer, with credit of course.

Answer (score 22):

Here's a method based on creating a `MeshRegion` from the text:

```
text = Style[HoldForm @ Sum[x^2, {x, 0, 10}], 100, Bold];    
graphics = First[text ~ExportString~ "PDF" ~ImportString~ "PDF"];    
region = DiscretizeGraphics[graphics, MaxCellMeasure -> 5];    
image = ExampleData[{"ColorTexture", "Kingwood"}];

RegionPlot[region, Frame -> False, BoundaryStyle -> Black, PlotStyle -> Texture[image]]
```

[image]

Or in 3D...

```
Plot3D[1, {x, y} ∈ region,
 PlotStyle -> Texture[image],
 Extrusion -> 10, BoxRatios -> Automatic,
 Mesh -> False, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

## Tiling

To tile the image you can use `TextureCoordinateFunction`, e.g:

```
RegionPlot[region, Frame -> False, BoundaryStyle -> Black, 
 PlotStyle -> Texture[image],
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({5 #1, 5 #2} &)]
```

[image]

Comment: Simon, I have been having trouble converting a PDF to `FilledCurve` graphics for a while now.  Here's what `graphics` looks like on my machine: http://i.stack.imgur.com/zCMGX.png.  What version and OS are you using?

Comment: @MichaelE2, I'm using Windows 7 (64 bit) and version 10. It worked fine with version 9 too.

Comment: thanks.  It works fine in V9 for me, too.  I have only a beta version of V10 -- waiting for my IT department to catch up to the update.  I'm hoping the bug will go away in the final release.

Comment: I've got to start using that new-to-me `Texture` stuff.  What's this `Extrusion` option for `Plot3D`?

Comment: Any clever approach that makes use of the new `Mesh` functions gets my vote.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, `Extrusion` is the new `Thickness` for `Plot3D`. See [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37684/862).

Comment: I'm not sure if I should open a new question, but ideally I am looking to tile the image.  Forgive me but I'm not certain if yours does such because I'm on v8(will be updated momentarily.)

Comment: @LiamWilliam, see update.

Comment: On version 9 but keep receiving `RegionPlot::argr: RegionPlot called with 1 argument; 3 arguments are expected.`

Comment: @LiamWilliam, ah - the `MeshRegion` stuff is new in version 10.

Comment: @SimonWoods Upgraded to M10!  I'm reading through the new mesh documentation, but I seem to be having issues forcing the tile to work.  For example I would like the tiled image not to be stretched in any way, but using your example it appears to be stretched.  Is there an easy way to generalize this also to images, for example `image = Graphics[{Black,Rectangle[]}]`.

Comment: @LiamWilliam, to avoid changing the aspect ratio of the texture you will need to use `AspectRatio -> Automatic` and `TextureCoordinateScaling -> False` along with a texture coordinate function like `(0.08 {#1, ar #2} &)` where `ar` is the aspect ratio of the texture image `ar = Divide@@ImageDimensions[image]` and the numerical factor is adjusted to give the desired number of tilings.

Answer (score 7):

Using Simon Woods' [shadow package](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43186/how-can-i-add-drop-shadows-and-specular-highlights-to-2d-graphics/43187) this is easy:

```
text = Style[HoldForm@Sum[x^2, {x, 0, 10}], 100, Bold];
image = ImageResize[Import["http://creativity103.com/collections/Graphic/rainbowbars.jpg"], ImageDimensions@Rasterize@text];
shadow[image, text]
```

[image: Example]

In the example above I stretched the background to fit the image of the equation. If you want to tile the background instead you can create your tiled background of the appropriate size using the following function:

```
createBackground[size_, pattern_] := Module[{scalex, scaley, vertices},
  {scalex, scaley} = size/ImageDimensions[pattern];
  vertices = {{0, 0}, {scalex, 0}, {scalex, scaley}, {0, scaley}};
  Graphics[{
    Texture[pattern],
    Polygon[
     vertices,
     VertexTextureCoordinates -> vertices
     ]
    }, ImageSize -> size, PlotRangePadding -> 0]
  ]
```

`size` is the total size of the background and `pattern` is the tile image. Typically you would set the size of the background to the size of the bounding box of the text that you're trying fill with the texture.

Comment: It didn't even occur to me to use *shadow* :-)