# How to add Thickness in ListContourPlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

How do you add a thickness to `ListContourPlot3D`. Extrusion works with `ContourPlot3D`, but `ListContourPlot3D` rejects it. I am using *Mathematica* 10 on a mac.

```
ListContourPlot3D[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 10, 10}], Contours -> {0}, 
Mesh -> None, MaxPlotPoints -> 60]
```

[image: What I am working with!]

Comment: What if you use it as a `ContourStyle` setting?

Comment: @J.M. What do you mean? `ContourStyle -> Extrusion -> 0.1`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using version 10.2-Linux, this undocumented option [`Extrusion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Extrusion.html) seems to work with [`ListContourPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListContourPlot3D.html)

```
dta = Table[
   x^3 + y^2 - z^2, {z, -2, 2, .1}, {y, -2, 2, .1}, {x, -2, 2, .1}];
Grid@Partition[#, 
    3] &@(ListContourPlot3D[dta, Contours -> {0}, Mesh -> None, 
     MaxPlotPoints -> 60, DataRange -> {#, #, #} &@{-2, 2}, 
     Extrusion -> #] & /@ Range[0, 0.3, .05])
```

[image]

Comment: Nice ! Works for me with 10.3 OSX (though `Extrusion` is  highlighted in red in the code).

Comment: [Related post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55021/19960). It would mean that since v10.2, the undocumented `Extrusion` option seems also to work with `ListContourPlot3D`.

Comment: It's all very odd.  In `RevolutionPlot3D` and `ParametricPlot3D` you can simply use `PlotStyle->Thickness[n]` where `n` is a number.  But for `Plot3D` you need to use this undocumented (red) option.

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to use ContourPlot3D with an interpolated version of the data list. For example:

```
tab = Flatten[Table[{{x, y, z}, RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}, 
    {x, -1, 1, 0.1}, {y, -1, 1, 0.1}, {z, -1, 1, 0.1}], 2];
fn = Interpolation[tab];
ContourPlot3D[fn[x, y, z], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, 
    Mesh -> None, Contours -> 1]
```

[image]