# Sharp Edges in ContourPlot3D with Thickness setting

Tags: plotting

I am using a ContourPlot3D to plot an object with thickness. I noticed that the edges in the negative region are sharp and distorted. Is there a way to remove these distortions?

Code is the following:

```
    ContourPlot3D[ x*z - y^2 == 0, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
      Mesh -> None, ContourStyle -> Thickness[0.1]]
```

Please note that this code works in Mathematica 9 but for some reason, the plot shows no thickness in Mathematica 10.

The distortion is shown below.

[image]

Comment: How about `ContourPlot3D[x z - y^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
 Contours -> {-0.1, 0.1}, Mesh -> None, ContourStyle -> Yellow]`? This works in `10`

Comment: @Feyre Yes it works in 10. But is it possible to fill the region between these contours? I need this for 3D printing.

Comment: Using the contours method is changing the shape of the object and I prefer other methods that could specify the thickness.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update**

Creating a table of data for the evaluated function allows for control of "grid" size and domain which produces the smoothest part once plotted.

```
data = Table[x*z - y^2, {z, -1, 1, 0.01}, {y, -1, 1, 0.01}, {x, -1, 1, 0.01}];
ListContourPlot3D[data, Contours -> {0}, Mesh -> None, 
   Extrusion -> 0.1, DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image]

---

Use the undocumented `Extrusion` option and increase `PlotPoints` for higher resolution:

```
ContourPlot3D[x*z - y^2 == 0, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
 Mesh -> None, Extrusion -> 0.1,PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", PlotPoints -> 500]
```

[image]

References:

[How to add Thickness in ListContourPlot3D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97757/how-to-add-thickness-in-listcontourplot3d)

[Increase 3D Graph thickness for 3D printing in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37684/increase-3d-graph-thickness-for-3d-printing-in-mathematica/55021#55021)

Comment: Is the ParametricPlot3D even plotting the same plot? It is not and I don't think I could use 3 variables with this. Extrusion is giving distortion again.

Comment: You can use ParametricPlot3D with your surface equation. I updated the answer. ContourPlot3D seems to be of better quality.

Comment: None of the methods are giving a result that I could use for 3D printing. The sharp edges are still there.

Comment: Having done a significant amount of high resolution 3D printing, using the first option with a high PlotPoint number would be sufficient.

Comment: @AbdulrahmanKalbat Take a look at the answer now, I've updated with a new method

Comment: Thanks a lot for the last method. It is really smooth and the STL file created has a reasonable size now.