# Increasing the thickness of a 3D surface

Tags: plotting

I am drawing a 3D surface with the following code:

```
S1 = 
  Plot3D[-69*(Cosh[(3*x)/299] - 1) + 200, {x, -200, 200}, {y, -1, 1}, 
    Mesh -> None, 
    BoxRatios -> {1, .1, 1}, 
    ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
    PlotPoints -> 40, 
    PlotStyle -> Thickness[10]];
Show[{S1}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

As you can see, I am attempting to increase the thickness of the function with the following term:

```
PlotStyle -> Thickness[10]
```

Yet, this does nothing. It stays thin. I have also tried changing the constant from 10 to .01. But this does nothing too. I have browsed the Wolfram documentation page and this forum, but I cannot quite find a solution. I appreciate any help with this.

Comment: `Thickness` is—I think—for lines, not for surfaces. You might consider using `RegionPlot3D` or using the `Filling` option instead.

Comment: There is an answer to this question found [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14954/filling-between-two-3d-surfaces)

Answer (score 13):

You can use `Extrusion`:

```
S1 = Plot3D[-69*(Cosh[(3*x)/299] - 1) + 200, {x, -200, 200}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 Mesh -> None, BoxRatios -> {1, .1, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotPoints -> 40, Extrusion -> 10];
Show[{S1}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Related:

[Sharp Edges in ContourPlot3D with Thickness setting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120400/sharp-edges-in-contourplot3d-with-thickness-setting/120403#120403)

Comment: Woah, I don't think I'd seen that before! Very cool.

Comment: @Young I am unable to find a reference to `Extrusion` in the documentation. Can you find it there?

Comment: @JackLaVigne I think it's an undocumented option

Answer (score 3):

I would try `RegionPlot3D` for this kind of work, depending on exactly what you're trying to generate (could we get more details?).

For example, you could try something like:

```
S1 = RegionPlot3D[-69*(Cosh[(3*x)/299] - 1) + 195 <= 
z <= -69*(Cosh[(3*x)/299] - 1) + 205, {x, -200, 200}, {y, -1, 
1}, {z, 0, 205}, BoxRatios -> {1, .1, 1}, 
ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotPoints -> 120, 
AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}];
Show[{S1}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

Which gives
[image: regionplot3d structure]

Comment: Thank you guys! It's now working.