# Technique for drawing polyhedron cutaway

Tags: graphics3d, polyhedra

Here is a graphic I drew with an earlier version of Mathematic (probably version 6) which I no longer have available:

[image: Sphere embedded in a truncated icosahedron]

At the time `Polyhedra` was an external package, and I produced the cut-away by truncating a list of component polyhedra of the truncated icosahedron before drawing.

Recent versions of Mathematica have an entirely different (and now integrated) set of polyhedron functions, that look nothing like what I used before. Can anyone suggest a strategy for redrawing this figure now?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: I guess you're referring to [`PolyhedronData["TruncatedIcosahedron"]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolyhedronData.html)?

Comment: Do you still have the old code, at least? Can you elaborate on how you "truncat(ed) a list of component polyhedra of the truncated icosahedron"?

Answer (score 5):

An adaptation of my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/37688/4999):

```
SeedRandom[3]; (* for reproducibility *)
With[{poly = PolyhedronData["TruncatedIcosahedron"] /. 
    Polygon[pp_] :> Polygon[RandomSample[pp, 24]]}, 
 With[{r0 = PolyhedronData["TruncatedIcosahedron", "Circumradius"],
       r1 = 1,                   (* input: r1 = inner boundary vertex distance *)
       r2 = 2},                  (* input: r2 = outer boundary vertex distance *)
  With[{pts = First@Cases[poly, 
       GraphicsComplex[p_, e__] :> Flatten[{p *(r1/r0), p*(r2/r0)}, 1],
       Infinity]}, 
   Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[pts,
     {EdgeForm[], Lighter@ColorData[97, 2],
      Cases[poly, Polygon[p_] :> Polygon@Join[p, p + Length[pts]/2], Infinity], 
      Cases[poly, 
       Polygon[p_] :> Polygon[
          Flatten[
           Join[#, Reverse@# + Length[pts]/2] & /@ Partition[#, 2, 1, 1] & /@ p,
           1]],
       Infinity]}
     ], PlotRange -> All, Options[poly]]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

- We remove the neiborhoods of one of the face of `TruncatedIcosahedron`.
- After we select the polygons, we add the original `{0,0,0}` to each polygons and use `ConvexHullMesh` to construct some pyramid.

```
adjfaces = 
 PolyhedronData["TruncatedIcosahedron", "AdjacentFaceIndices"]
face = 1;
indexs = 
  Complement[adjfaces // Flatten // DeleteDuplicates, 
   Select[adjfaces, MemberQ[#, face] &] // Flatten // 
    DeleteDuplicates];
polys = PolyhedronData["TruncatedIcosahedron", "Polygons"][[indexs]];
Graphics3D[{polys /. 
   Polygon[pts_] :> ConvexHullMesh[Append[pts, {0, 0, 0}]], 
  SphericalPlot3D[1, {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 2  Pi}][[1]]}, 
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

- To view the sphere, we remove one more polygon.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
adjfaces= PolyhedronData["TruncatedIcosahedron", "AdjacentFaceIndices"];
g = UndirectedEdge @@@adjfaces//Graph;
face = 1;
indexs1 = AdjacencyList[g, face, 1];
indexs2 = AdjacencyList[g, face, 2];
indexs = 
  Complement[VertexList[g], 
   Join[{face}, indexs1, {Complement[indexs2, indexs1][[5]]}]];
polys = PolyhedronData["TruncatedIcosahedron", "Polygons"][[indexs]];
Graphics3D[{polys /. 
   Polygon[pts_] :> ConvexHullMesh[Append[pts, {0, 0, 0}]], 
  SphericalPlot3D[1, {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}][[1]]}, 
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Remove faces visible from a given view point and extrude the remaining faces:

```
ClearAll[visibleVerts, facesKept, intrudeFace]
visibleVerts[viewp_] := Intersection[
   MeshCoordinates[#], 
   MeshCoordinates[
    RegionDifference[ConvexHullMesh[Prepend[MeshCoordinates[#], viewp]], #]]] &

facesKept[viewp_] := Select[x |-> DisjointQ[x[[1]], visibleVerts[viewp] @ #]] @ 
  MeshPrimitives[#, 2] &

intrudeFace[scaledThickness_, p_ : {0, 0, 0}] := ConvexHullMesh[Join[First @ #, 
    ScalingTransform[(1 - scaledThickness) {1, 1, 1}, p] @ First @ #], ##2] &
```

***Examples:***

```
{bmr, cb} = PolyhedronData["TruncatedIcosahedron",
   {"BoundaryMeshRegion", "CoordinateBounds"}];

zh = 1.2;
vp = {0, 0, zh cb[[-1, -1]] };
t = .3;


Row[{Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5], Red, facesKept[vp][bmr]}, 
    Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> Medium], 
  Show[intrudeFace[t] /@ facesKept[vp][bmr], ImageSize -> Medium],
  Show[intrudeFace[t][#, MeshCellStyle -> {{2, All} :> RandomColor[]}] & /@ 
    facesKept[vp][bmr], 
  Graphics3D[{Red, 
   Ball[{0, 0, 0},
     (1 - t) PolyhedronData["TruncatedIcosahedron", "Circumradius"]]}],
  ImageSize -> Medium]}, 
 Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Use `zh = 1.5` to get

[image]

and `zh = 4` to get

[image]

With `zh = 1.1` combined with varies thickness values we get

```
Multicolumn[
 Table[Show[intrudeFace[s] /@ facesKept[vp][bmr], 
   Lighting -> "Neutral", ImageSize -> Medium, 
   PlotLabel -> Row[{"thicknes: ", s}]], {s, {.1, .3, .5, 1}}], 
 2, Dividers -> All, Appearance -> "Horizontal"]
```

[image]